# Route weighted traffic internally with Istio across K8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, amazon-eks

I have 2 applications (Web and Api) and there is 2 services and 2 Istio virtualServices respectively. Also there is 2 versions(v1 and v2) of each services.

I wish to do 3 things-

1. For Web, all traffic except **test-user** will route **100%** to version **v1** only.
2. For Web, for **test-user** traffic will route **100%** to version **v2** only (This is vice-versa of 1st point.). Before going to live, QA team will perform testing on version **v2**, once verified by QA team, will move traffic to **100%** to **v2** for every user and delete the version **v1**.
3. For Api, traffic will distribute **95%** for version **v1**(stable) and **5%** for version **v2**(release).

Web Manifest file:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: web-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - web.example.com
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        end-user:
          exact: test-user
    route:
    - destination:
        host: web-svc
        subset: v2
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: web-svc
        subset: v1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-svc
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: web
```

API manifest file:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: api-vs    -------------> #1
spec:
  hosts:
  - api-svc
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: api-svc
        subset: v1
        weight: 95
    - destination:
        host: api-svc
        subset: v2
        weight: 5
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-svc    -------------> #2
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: api
```

Traffic routing policy-

1. When we will hit the url **web.example.com** and it will serve the traffic from service **web-svc**. (This has been setup)
2. In the backend, service **web-svc** will call service **api-svc** internally and service **api-svc** will distribute the traffic **95%** to **v1** and **5%** to **v2** respectivley. (This is what I am struggling to do with wieghted routing.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with indentations and hosts. From [Istio docs](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#more-about-routing-rules), try like this:

> ```
> hosts:
> - api-svc
> http:
> - route:
>   - destination:
>       host: api-svc
>       subset: v1
>     weight: 95
>   - destination:
>       host: api-svc
>       subset: v2
>     weight: 5
> ```

Edited: destination hosts.

Comment: From service "web-svc" (which is only exposed to internet) want to call service "api-svc" internally such that-

1. web-svc --> 95% times will call api-svc on v1

2. web-svc --> 05% times will call api-svc on v2

Note: Please ignore indentations in the yaml snippet.

Comment: The hosts are mismatched in destination. Edited answer accordingly with reference.

Comment: I have updated the my case with marking- #1 and #2.     

What happend when k8s service "web-svc" internally calls k8s service "api-svc"? Will traffic be serve directly from k8s service "api-svc" (i.e; hop count=1) or traffic will route through istio virtualService "api-vs" to k8 service "api-svc" (i.e; hop count=2) ?

Comment: As far as I understand and from the information you provided I think that it should work like this:

If the traffic is external: 

Istio-ingressgateway goes to -> Gateway -> VS -> Service and lastly to the Pod.

Hope this helps clear things up a bit.